# sufficient statistic for a strange parameter on normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$  identically indepedent and distributed like   $N(b,1)$ .

I'm supposed to find a sufficient statistic for $a=P[X_1<1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
a=\Pr(X_1<1) = \Pr(X_1-b < 1-b) = \Phi(1-b)
$$
so $a$ is a one-to-one function of $b$. Since the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is the same for all values of $b$, and $a$ and $b$ determine each other completely, you can say that the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is the same for all values of $a.$

Comment: So if I understand corretly the explicit form of my sufficient statistic would be  $ X_1+\ldots,+X_n$? actually to be more accurate it would be the same sufficient statistic as the sufficient statistic of b ?

Comment: Correct. A sufficient statistic is for a family of probability distributions, and the two parameters, $a$ and $b,$ since they completely determine each other, both parametrize the _same_ family of probability distributions. $\qquad$