# Relation between MLE and minimal sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have four true false question about the relation between MLE(maximum likelihood estimator) and minimal sufficient statistic. let a minimal sufficient statistic exists and denoted by $S(x)$. let $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ is a random
sample from a distribution  $f_\theta(\cdot )$.I use notation $x=(x_1, \cdots, x_n).$

**Q1)**  The maximum likelihood estimator always is a function of minimal sufficient statistic. true or false?

**Q2)**
"MLE  always is a function of the minimal sufficient statistic, if MLE is unique". true or false?

**Q3)** If MLE is not unique, so we can find an MLE such that is not a function of  the minimal sufficient statistic. true or false?

**Q4)** If MLE is not unique, so we can find an MLE such that is  a function of  the minimal sufficient statistic. true or false?

Since $S(x)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic so We can write $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n,\theta)=h(x)g(S(x),\theta)$ and we expected MLE be is not a function of $S(x)$.

I think an example could help us to answer the questions.
Let $x_1, \cdots, x_n$  is a random sample from $Uniform(\theta -\frac{1}{2}, \theta +\frac{1}{2})$.

So a minimal sufficient statistic is $S=(x_{(1)}=\min (x_1, \cdots, x_n),x_{(n)}=\max
(x_1, \cdots, x_n)).$

$$L(\theta)=f_\theta(x_1,\cdots , x_n)=1_{\left( x_{(n)}-\frac{1}{2},x_{(1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}(\theta).$$

So any value in $\left( x_{(n)}-\frac{1}{2},x_{(1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is an MLE of $\theta$, like $\frac{x_{(1)}+x_{(n)}}{2}$.

Let define $W=\cos^2(x_2) (x_{(n)}-\frac{1}{2})+\sin^2(x_2) (x_{(1)}+\frac{1}{2})$. So it is an MLE too, but is not a function of the minimal sufficient statistic.

**Q1:"The maximum likelihood estimator always is a function of sufficient statistic"** is not true.
$W=\cos^2(x_2) (x_{(n)}-\frac{1}{2})+\sin^2(x_2) (x_{(1)}+\frac{1}{2})$ is a counter  example

**Q2)"If MLE is unique, MLE is always a function of the minimal sufficient statistic"** is true.

I am not sure here but Since $S(x)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic so We can write $f(x,\theta)=h(x)g(S(x),\theta)$ and we expected MLE be a function of $S(x)$, since maximization of $f(x,\theta)$ depend on $g(S(x),\theta)$ and $g$ depend on $x$ only through $S(x)$ .

**Q3):** **"If MLE is not unique, so we can find an MLE such that is not a function of  the minimal sufficient statistic"** is true. $W=\cos^2(x_2) (x_{(n)}-\frac{1}{2})+\sin^2(x_2) (x_{(1)}+\frac{1}{2})$ is an example.

**Q4) "If MLE is not unique, so we can find an MLE such that is  a function of  the minimal sufficient statistic"** is true. $\frac{x_{(1)}+x_{(n)}}{2}$ is an example.

Comment: I think you are right. Similar discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047416/321264.